# Finding probability of books

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find the probability of books in certain situations.

Suppose you have $40$ different books ($20$ math books, $15$ history books, and $5$ geography books).

a) You pick two books at random, one at a time. What is the probability that the two books are from different disciplines?

I think I was able to get the answer for the first part:

$$1-\frac{20⋅19+15⋅14+5⋅4}{40⋅39}.$$

b) You pick $5$ books at random, with replacement, one at a time. What is the probability that you’ve picked books from at most two disciplines?

I am not sure to find the probability for this. How to set it up?

Answer (score 1):

There are $40^5$ equally likely sequences of $5$ books. We find the number of **good** sequences, that is, sequences that have at most two disciplines. We will use the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion.

There are $35^5$ good sequences that contain math and/or history, $25^5$ that contain math and/or history, and $20^5$ that contain history and/or geography.

If we add these three numbers together, we will have double-counted the math-only sequences, also the history-only, also the geography-only.

Thus the number of good sequences is $35^5+25^5+20^5-20^5-15^5-5^5$. Divide by $40^5$. To make the arithmetic easy, note that each term is divisible by $5^5$.

Answer (score 0):

for b) the probability is $P=\sum_{k+l+m=5, k\ge 1, l\ge 1, m \ge 1} \frac{5!}{k!l!m!}\left(\frac{20}{40}\right)^k\left(\frac{15}{40}\right)^l\left(\frac{5}{40}\right)^m$